# Understanding distribution of distributions

Tags: distributions, bayesian, posterior

I was studying Bayesian plausibility but was stuck on some basic concepts. Bayesian plausibility condition is an equation that says $$\int_{\Delta(\Omega)}pd\mu(p) = P$$ Where $P$ is the prior distribution, $\mu()$ is a distribution over posterior distributions while $\Delta(\Omega)$ is the set of posterior distributions over the state space $\Omega$. A lemma points out that a distribution of posterior distributions $\mu()$ can be generated by Bayesian updating based on a likelihood function $\sigma$ provided that the plausibility condition above is satisfied.

Now, my question is how there can be a distribution of posterior distribution? Isn't the posterior distribution uniquely and completely determined by Bayes' Theorem? If Bayesian updating can generate different posterior distributions, what is the logic behind it?